# A counting problem from an exam and my solution for it, can I submit an appeal?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

The problem is:

How many subsets of {${1,2,...,n}$} have an even sum of their elements?

**Please take a look at my solution since this is my answer from the exam and I think to appeal on this question, I'd like to hear your thoughts if I can appeal this.**

I decided to solve this problem by recursive formula, my solution:

Let's define:
 $a_{n}$ - The number of subsets of {${1,2,...,n}$} that have an even sum of their elements.

Let's split into two different cases:

$*$1. $n$ is odd, therefore in this case we got: $2^{n-1}-a_{n-1}$
2. $n$ is even, therefore in this case we got: $a_{n-1}$

**$*$ EXPLANATION:** $2^{n-1}$ is the number of subsets of {${1,2,...,n}$}.
$a_{n-1}$ is the number of subsets of {${1,2,...,n}$} that have an even sum of their elements like I defined.  Therefore $2^{n-1}-a_{n-1}$ is the number of subsets of {1,2,...,n} that have an **odd** sum of their elements.

From summarize the cases we got: $a_{n} = 2^{n-1}-a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}$, Therefore $a_{n} = 2^{n-1}$

The answer to the main question is $a_{11} = 2^{11-1} = 2^{10}$.

The comment I got from my teacher about this answer is about the split into the cases, he wrote that $n$ don't have to be a part of the group and he is completely right.

In fact, my final answer was right,  but my split into the two cases is completely wrong and I received 0% points for this answer.
I would like to appeal this question in claiming that I meant other cases separation and it was only a formulation mistake.

I'll be glad if someone can tell me if it makes sense, and if it is, how to formulate it right to gain some points.

Comment: So let me get this straight: You agree that your answer is wrong, but you want to get more than 0% for it? That's not something we can help you with. Whether that's the right score you should get, or something which should be worth a somewhat higher score is _entirely_ up to whoever gave you that 0%.

Comment: Incorrect or insufficient work shown that has a correct answer is a 0%- almost everywhere.

Comment: sorry, but I agree with the grader...the proof, as shown, doesn't work.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "other cases separation." There is a second mistake, where you make the assertion that $a_n$ is the sum of the number of even subsets you would get if $n$ were even plus the number you would get if $n$ were odd. That is tantamount to saying that every integer $n$ is both odd and even. A third error: you undercounted the number of subsets of $n$ elements by a factor of $2.$ I notice also that you have no base case, which should be a clue to you that  your formula isn't actually recursive. (It isn't.)

Comment: I agree with you that how it was written is absolutely wrong, but in the exam itself I thought somehow that $n$ representing an element from a current subset and that what confused me. (as if I were split it by the biggest element in the current subset)
I just want to know if I can make my mistake a formatting mistake and appeal it or it is a drastic one and there is no way back.

Comment: I agree - attempting to reason through it should not warrant the same score as if you'd left it blank.  That said, it is harsh, but as long as the professor is grading the rest of the class in the same way, I wouldn't worry.  In the end, you appear to have a reasonable mathematical mind and a strong interest in the truth, and because of that, you will finish well above average.